# Execute big amount of parametrized JUnit tests as they come instead of when they're all available

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, parameterized

I'm working on a project with generated junit tests. There are about **8 200 000** junit tests to execute. I have one test which does the testing and an interator which generate data to test on "next()" method. But what I've found out is that JUnit first generate all parameters for all tests and when that's all available then the actual testing begin.
Unfortunately executing such huge amount of tests take over 2h just to generate all test cases and ends with OutOfMemoryError even with Xmx16g and Xms1g. But when executed one by one without generating them all first it's ok (when I have one test which generate data for test and test it instantly). But it is just one test for all. I'd like it to be available as multiple tests just as JUnit does it normally but without pregenerating data first.

Is there any way in JUnit (4/5) to execute test each time next() is called on iterator? and execute tests as long as hasNext() returns true?

I know that in such example there's no way to show progress of testing but that's ok for me. I just want to execute them and then when they're finished I want to look at html report. Only thing is that sometimes I want to execute tests in eclipse and then have a look at results in eclipse (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't conduct deep search on this topic but from what I've found already it turns out, that JUnit 4 is not capable of doing such thing. It has to pre-generate params first, process them generating testcases and then execute them.

For simple test which just pass single int to test and execute test which does nothing, generating 2 million ints will make whole thing wait for over 1h (I just stopped waiting after 1h) and even first test will not start executing.

So only way to execute such big amount of tests is to execute them in single test and then manually store results of test.

In other words: write your own testing execution mechanism inside junit test case.

I'll leave this answer here. If you dear reader know a way to overcome this (possibly in newer JUnit than JUnit 4) please post an answer.